# When does Hadamard product rank upper bound hold?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, upper-lower-bounds, hadamard-product

We know $rank(A\circ B)\leq rank(A)rank(B)$. Under what conditions do we have equality?

Comment: A *sufficient* condition for equality is that one of matrices has rank $1$ and no non-zero entries.  I'm not sure about a more general description.

Comment: @turbo I am interested in the same question. Did you find something?