# How to prove Hadamard product rank upper bound hold?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, upper-lower-bounds, hadamard-product

In [enter link description here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2599974/when-does-hadamard-product-rank-upper-bound-hold?newreg=a64f1e37c66d4194aeb3bfef3e73b40c),
@Ben Grossmann mentioned that if one of the matrices has rank 1 and no non-zero entries, $rank(A\circ B)= rank(A)rank(B)$.

My progress is as follows, where the superscript $(\cdot)^H$ indicates conjugate transposition.

Let $r_A=1$ and $r_B$ are ranks of $A$ and $B$. Using, e.g., the SVD, $A$ and $B$ can be written as
$$
A=p_1q_1^H, \quad B=\sum_{j=1}^{r_B}s_jt_j^H,
$$
for some vectors $p_1$, $q_1$, $s_j$, $t_j$, $j=1,\ldots,r_B$.
Further, we have
$$
A\circ B=\sum_{j=1}^{r_B}(p_1\circ s_j)(q_1\circ t_j)^H,
$$
so $A\circ B$ is a sum of $r_B$ rank-one matrices and thus its rank cannot be higher than $r_B$.

The next step is to show
$$
rank\left[\sum_{j=1}^{r_B}(p_1\circ s_j)(q_1\circ t_j)^H\right]=r_B,
$$
which seems not trivial.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This question likely won't be recieved very well because you haven't shown any of your own efforts or thoughts about how to approach this problem. Take a look at [this guide](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hint: $A\circ B$ is a submatrix of $A\otimes B$.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/812556)

Comment: @user1551 The rank of submatrix is less than or equal to that of the matrix so it can only be obtained that $rank(A \circ B)\leq rank(B)$. How to prove the equality holds in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick proof. Suppose (without loss of generality) that $A$ is rank $1$ with all non-zero entries. Let $u,v$ be column-vectors such that $A = uv^T$; notably, $u,v$ also have only non-zero entries. It follows that $D_u = \operatorname{diag}(u)$ and $D_v = \operatorname{diag}(v)$ are invertible matrices. Thus, we have
$$
\operatorname{rank}(A \circ B) = \operatorname{rank}(D_u BD_v) = \operatorname{rank}(B) = \operatorname{rank}(A) \cdot \operatorname{rank}(B),
$$
which was what we wanted.